# Глобальные переменные и переменные окружения это одно и то же?

Tags: переменные

Хотел бы узнать, чем отличаются глобальные переменные от переменных окружения или это одно и то же?

Comment: Язык программирования какой?

Comment: можно узнать о каком языке идет речь?

Comment: глобальными принято называть переменные внутри самого языка программирования, доступные из всех мест программы. А переменные окружения - это специальные переменные операционной системы для приема информации из вне программы

Comment: @Streletz да впринципе

Answer (score 5):

Это разные сущности.

[Переменные окружения/среды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B) (environment variables) это некие текстовые переменные создаваемые ОС и хранящие информацию о настройках системы.

В Windows/Unix их список можно посмотреть набрав с консоли:

set

Пример:

```
HOME=/home/vivek
vivek@nas01:~$ env
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=9ee90112ba2cb349f07bfe2f00002e46-1381581541.324726-906214463
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.6 60190 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=vivek
MAIL=/var/mail/vivek
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
PWD=/home/vivek
LANG=en_IN
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/vivek
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LOGNAME=vivek
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.6 60190 192.168.1.10 22
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Глобальные переменные, это совсем другая история:

> В программировании глобальной переменной называют переменную, областью видимости которой является вся программа